# How to wire a sub panel from a 15 amp circuit existing run

Tags: wiring, subpanel, pond

I'm adding power for an outdoor pond, I will need four outlets in the end.  I have an existing 15 amp circuit out of my main house service panel that connects to an outside wall.  I want to tie into that with 12-2 and run it about 80 feet away (buried in rigid conduit) and it was suggested that I put a small sub panel on the remote end to help isolate that run later (Question 1. Is the sub panel unnecessary in the first place?).  In the end I need four GFI outlets near the pond.

Concept: I was going to take a typical AC disconnect box and swap in a new 15 amp breaker.  The question is about the wiring.  The AC disconnect box has two main lugs and what I guess is the neutral bar at the bottom.  I'm guessing I need to add a ground bar and then my incoming 12-2 will connect this way:  Hot (black) to one of those lugs, Neutral (white) goes to the neutral bar, Ground (bare copper) goes to new ground bar.  I assume the ground bar and neutral bar are *not* bonded in this scenario?  Should I also bury a ground rod and tie that panel's new ground bar to the ground rod?  From this new breaker I'll run the two new outlets in a separate weather proof box.  I will use one GFI and then connect the second standard outlet on the load side so they're both protected.  Have I described it proper or did I miss something major?
Thanks!

**UPDATE: Answering questions**
Load to consider on the pond end:

- Pump: 12 Volt, 28 Watts, 60Hz,
- UV: 120 Volt, 60Hz, 9 Watt UV Lamp
- LED: 0.76 Watts

There is a single outlet on the existing circuit.

Comment: What loads are you trying to feed there?  Also, are there other receptacles on this existing branch circuit?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a shutoff or subpanel for a single outdoor circuit.

You should not put 4 GFCI receptacles outdoors if you can avoid it.

The best way to handle the GFCI requirement is to find a place along the circuit still inside your dry house.  Put the GFCI there, whee itvwon't get destroyed by weather.   You know how to use the LOAD terminals on a GFCI to protect downline things, so do exactly that *for your entire outdoor circuit*.

Now, because the wiring is also protected, you are allowed to use direct burial at 12" cover.   Though since you are using Rigid, you only need 6" cover.  You can use THWN individual wires in the conduit and do not need a ground since Rigid is the ground.

Comment: I've already run the 12-2 underground, that's OK vs the THWN right? @Harper

Comment: @kcap -- is that 12/2 UF cable (the grey stuff without the paper separator) or NM?  Also, is it buried to the correct depth?

Comment: It's the 12/2 NM, it's at 8" @ThreePhaseEel

Comment: @kcap -- you'll need to dig it up then, sorry man....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- well, luckily I haven't fully buried it, but it does mean I have to run 80 feet again.  I'll probably invest in a fish tape rather than pull the rigid apart.  So, the 12/2 UF is exactly what I need?  I will end up leaving out the sub panel concept also as Harper mentions since I don't need it.  Any other thoughts on this one?  Thanks a lot.

Comment: @kcap -- ah, I didn't see you were trying to jam that 12/2 down a conduit :) I'd just get a pair of 12AWG THHNs and use the outgoing cable as a pull-string -- stuffing a cable down that conduit is simply making your life harder than it needs to be.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- just to confirm.  I would only pull a black THHN and a white THHN, Harper mentioned no need for the Ground (bare)?  Obviously, I'm newer to this type of thing, so just re-confirming there is no need for a Ground "bare" wire?  Is it simply because it's in the "ground", even though it runs up out of the ground on the outlet end?

Comment: @kcap -- metal conduit is permitted to serve as a grounding conductor, so you don't need a wire-type grounding conductor inside it

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- by use of Rigid I meant the grey PVC CANTEX, guessing that does not count?

Comment: @kcap -- oh, if it's PVC, then you buried it too shallow :P and yes, you will need a green THHN or bare copper for the ground in that case.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- well, in that case I'll just go with UF-B and bury it 12" in that already run conduit.  That cable is cheaper than buying 3 colors of the THHN/THWN-2 @ 100' each.

Comment: @kcap -- eh, it's a fool's economy when you can't get the cable wrestled down the conduit :P

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- ok, then maybe i'll go THHN/THWN-2 on that point alone. However when I look up that type of cable, I see comments like:  "When used as a THHN" suitable in dry areas. What's the difference between these THHN and THWN-2 wires?  And how do you use THHN as THWN-2? How do I know if I can run it in the conduit underground?

Comment: @kcap -- ignore those comments re: the cable

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel -- so something like this is good? https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00FI6R1OE/ref=twister_B072218R6Y?_encoding=UTF8&th=1

Comment: @kcap -- better to go with stranded wire, as that will be easier to pull down the conduit